# date_format:H:i not working while editing form in laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am doing project in laravel. There is a form containing fields as 'start_time' and 'end_time'. While creating form I used following validation rules in EventRequest.php file

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'start_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
        'end_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i|after:start_time',];

}
```

This works well while creating form and storing values in database. There is a option as 'edit form' in my project.When I clicked edit form button then another form opens with database values so that we can edit, but I try to edit the value and click on Edit button then this shows me an error message as, 
"**The start time does not match the format H:i.
The end time does not match the format H:i.**".

I don't know what's wrong with this. My database have columns as 'start_time' and 'end_time' with datatype 'time'. Please give any suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked what values exactly are you sending to the form?

Comment: Yes after submitting form this sends values to the database as '13:12:00' and '14:12:00' for 'start_time' and 'end_time' fields

Comment: What do you mean? You said that you're getting error messages. That means that no data should be saved. What exactly are you sending to the server? Not what the server is sending to the database

Comment: First time when I create form then it works well, without showing any error message data gets stored successfully to the database but when I tried to edit the form by clicking on the edit button then it shows me a form with database values and at that time when I try to submit form by editing time then it shows me that error message.

Comment: So, what values are being sent to the server when you're shown the error message?

Comment: It just shows the error message if I don't change the time values in the form and try to submit form as it is. Its sending an empty value, but why its taking empty value at start though it shows value in the form field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94424/discussion-between-amarja-and-satisfaction).